# File sharing between Windows 7pro and windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-10

I have been trying to share drive from my old laptop(windows 7 pro) to the new one (windows 10 home). but I am getting an error every time. I have followed all the regarding sharing.

- Assign the unique IP address to both systems.
- Used good quality LAN cable wire.
- Turn all the network sharing options.
- Grant all the permission like (everyone, Owner rights)

But still, it shows an error **"Windows can not access \MYPCNAME"**

[image]

The issue is I can view my old pc into networks but when I start copying data from old pc to new pc using the network it shows error.

Please tell me where I did mistake??

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IP address of the machine you want to connect to.

To use DNS (hostname) you have to have it setup on the network with a device resolving DNS names.

To find out each machines ip number, go to start and type cmd then enter. In the window that comes up type in "ipconfig" then enter and look for the local area connections IP number.

Use the same format but with IP numbers you just grabbed from command prompt.
 Example:
"\\192.168.1.100\shared-folder-name"

Also if your not plugged into a switch or router you  need a t568a/t568b cross-over cable. But you will know if you do, when you don't get a link LED on both computers.

Comment: Thank you so much! There was an issue with the LAN driver.

Comment: You should write up as a detailed of an answer as you can. That way if someone else has the same problem they will find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I dig a lot of network sharing option, IP address but still issue was there. 
After a lot of efforts, I decided to re-install Network driver and My issue is resolved. It is working like charm!!!.

So who has an issue like I had please check Network driver once.

Thanks!